# How To Configure the Terminal in Code

Tags: settings, code

The question says it all. I would like to configure the integrated terminal of Code (especially get rid of some lurid colours), but I can't find any option to do so, nor any configuration file.

How do I configure the appearance of the terminal?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal plugin in Code follows the settings of the main Terminal application. To edit these settings:

1. Close Code and open Terminal.
2. Run `sudo apt install dconf-editor`, then close Terminal once the package is installed.
3. Open *dconf Editor* from the Applications menu.
4. Navigate to `/io/elementary/terminal/settings`

[image: terminal settings]

You can now edit any of these settings by clicking on them. If you're interested in changing the colors of the interface, you'll probably be most interested in *background*, *foreground*, and *palette*. *Background* is obviously the background color, *foreground* is the main text color, and *palette* is the colors of various other features (this might require some trial and error to figure out what each of them actually controls).

Note that to get these changes to update in the Code plugin, you may need to Disable it and Enable it again in Code's settings.